# HTML Input value in angular2

Tags: html, angular

I am working on a an angular2 project and i setted the value of html element (input) value to 0 as follows

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="balance">Balance</label>
  <input ngModel type="number" class="form-control" id="balance" placeholder="Balance" name="balance" value="0" required>
</div>
```

but when i run the project i get empty input.
any help?

Comment: when I run this code snippet I got Balance 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="balance">Balance</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="balance" placeholder="Balance" name="balance" [(ngModel)]="balance" required>
</div>
```

In your component constructor

```
balance:number;
constructor(){
   this.balance = 0;
}
```